# Stuck while optimizing a segmented prime sieve in C

Tags: c, optimization, primes

I'm trying to implement an efficient segmented prime sieve in C. It's basically a sieve of Eratosthenes, but each segment is split to a size that can well fit in cache.

In my version, there is a bit array of flags in which each bit is a consecutive odd number. Each bit is erased by masking with `AND` when it is a multiple of a known prime number.

This single part of code consumes about 90% of runtime. Each dirty bit of code has a reason for it that I explained in comments, but the overall operation is very simple.

1. Grab a prime number.
2. Calculate its square and its multiple that is slightly bigger than the number that the starting point of the cache block represents.
3. Take the bigger one.
4. Erase the bit, add the base prime number to itself two times, and repeat until the end of the cache block.

And that's it.

There is a program called `primesieve` which can do this operation very fast. It is about 3 times faster than my version. I read its documentation about the algorithm and also its code, and applied whatever is plausible to my code.

Since there is a known program a lot faster than mine, I will investigate further what they're doing and what I'm not, but before that, I posted this question to get extra help if you can help me find out which part is not running efficiently.

Saying again, this single routine consumes 90% of runtime, so I'm really focused on making this part run faster.

This is the old version, I've made some modifications after the post, and that one's below this one. The comments still apply.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//size of the cache block (64K)
#define C 0x10000

static unsigned sq(unsigned a) {
    return a * a;
}

//`f` is the array of flags. `st` is the starting point being a multiple of
//`C * 16`. Each byte can hold 16 odd numbers, thus having `C` multiplied by 16.
//`p` is the array of prime numbers from 67 up to `sqrt(st + C * 16)`. Primes
//below 67 are handled specially by other routines.
__attribute__((noinline)) //Don't inline for testing.
static void sieve_bit(unsigned *f, unsigned st, unsigned *p) {
    //Doing table access than computing the mask in runtime was about 15% faster
    //on my machine. I'm guessing that probably the bit-shifts on x86 only being
    //able to use the CL register as a variable counter creates a dependency
    //when there is a series of shifts, making it slower than multiple L1 cache
    //accesses.
    static const unsigned m[] = {
        ~(1u << 0),  ~(1u << 1),  ~(1u << 2),  ~(1u << 3),  ~(1u << 4),
        ~(1u << 5),  ~(1u << 6),  ~(1u << 7),  ~(1u << 8),  ~(1u << 9),
        ~(1u << 10), ~(1u << 11), ~(1u << 12), ~(1u << 13), ~(1u << 14),
        ~(1u << 15), ~(1u << 16), ~(1u << 17), ~(1u << 18), ~(1u << 19),
        ~(1u << 20), ~(1u << 21), ~(1u << 22), ~(1u << 23), ~(1u << 24),
        ~(1u << 25), ~(1u << 26), ~(1u << 27), ~(1u << 28), ~(1u << 29),
        ~(1u << 30), ~(1u << 31)
    };
    unsigned p2 = sq(*p);
    do {
        unsigned r = st % *p;
        //This calculates the starting point. The result of `n` will be an odd
        //number multiple of `*p` a bit larger than `st`.
        unsigned n = st + *p - r + (-(r & 1) & *p);
        //If the square of `*p` is larger than `n`, use it instead.
        if (p2 > n) {
            n = p2;
        }
        //The loop is unrolled 8 times, which gave the fastest result on my
        //machine.
        for (;; n += *p * 16) {
            //Jumps to the next stage when there are no space left for 8
            //operations to be done. This could simply be a `break` followed by
            //a loop, but this was slightly (1~3%) faster than the simpler
            //alternative.
            int d = st + C * 16 - n;
            //as mentioned in the comments, the value of `d` relies on
            //implementation dependent behaviour for 2's complement machines.
            //`n` can be larger than `st + C * 16`, in which case the wrapped
            //unsigned value is converted to a negative `int`.
            if (d <= (int)*p * 14) {
                if (d <= (int)*p * 6) {
                    if (d <= (int)*p * 2) {
                        if (d <= (int)*p * 0) goto L0; else goto L1;
                    } else {
                        if (d <= (int)*p * 4) goto L2; else goto L3;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (d <= (int)*p * 10) {
                        if (d <= (int)*p * 8) goto L4; else goto L5;
                    } else {
                        if (d <= (int)*p * 12) goto L6; else goto L7;
                    }
                }
            }
            //The multiples of primes are erased.
            #define ur(i) do {\
                unsigned _n = (n - st) / 2 + *p * i;\
                f[_n / 32] &= m[_n % 32];\
            } while (0)
            ur(0); ur(1); ur(2); ur(3); ur(4); ur(5); ur(6); ur(7);
        }
        //Erase with the leftovers.
        L7: ur(6);
        L6: ur(5);
        L5: ur(4);
        L4: ur(3);
        L3: ur(2);
        L2: ur(1);
        L1: ur(0);
        L0:
        p2 = sq(*++p);
        #undef ur
    } while (p2 < st + C * 16);
}

//This could break if `TscInvariant` CPUID is false, which is probably rare on
//modern machines?
static inline unsigned long long rdtscp() {
    unsigned _;
    return __builtin_ia32_rdtscp(&_);
}

//This isn't used in actuall code. Just a simple one for a test. Fill with prime
//numbers enough to sieve all 32-bit primes.
static inline void fillPrimes(unsigned *p) {
    for (unsigned n = 67, c = 2; n <= 65521; n += c ^= 6) {
        for (unsigned d = 5, c = 4; d * d <= n; d += c ^= 6) {
            if (!(n % d)) goto next;
        }
        *p++ = n;
    next:;
    }
}

int main() {
    unsigned p[8000];
    fillPrimes(p);
    unsigned f[C / sizeof(unsigned)];
    puts("start sieve");
    unsigned long long c = rdtscp();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2000; ++i) {
        volatile unsigned *vf = f;
        sieve_bit((unsigned *)vf, C * 16 * i, p);
    }
    c = rdtscp() - c;
    printf("%llu\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

---

After having a rest, I could find some redundant calculations inside the loop, and taking them out gained about 6~7% speed.

```
static void sieve_bit(unsigned *f, unsigned st, unsigned *p) {
    static const unsigned m[] = {
        ~(1u << 0),  ~(1u << 1),  ~(1u << 2),  ~(1u << 3),  ~(1u << 4),
        ~(1u << 5),  ~(1u << 6),  ~(1u << 7),  ~(1u << 8),  ~(1u << 9),
        ~(1u << 10), ~(1u << 11), ~(1u << 12), ~(1u << 13), ~(1u << 14),
        ~(1u << 15), ~(1u << 16), ~(1u << 17), ~(1u << 18), ~(1u << 19),
        ~(1u << 20), ~(1u << 21), ~(1u << 22), ~(1u << 23), ~(1u << 24),
        ~(1u << 25), ~(1u << 26), ~(1u << 27), ~(1u << 28), ~(1u << 29),
        ~(1u << 30), ~(1u << 31)
    };
    unsigned p2 = sq(*p);
    do {
        unsigned n =
        (p2 > st + *p * 2 ? p2 - st : *p - st % *p + (-(st % *p & 1) & *p)) / 2;
        for (;; n += *p * 8) {
            int d = C * 8 - (int)n;
            if (d <= (int)*p * 7) {
                if (d <= (int)*p * 3) {
                    if (d <= (int)*p * 1) {
                        if (d <= (int)*p * 0) goto L0; else goto L1;
                    } else {
                        if (d <= (int)*p * 2) goto L2; else goto L3;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (d <= (int)*p * 5) {
                        if (d <= (int)*p * 4) goto L4; else goto L5;
                    } else {
                        if (d <= (int)*p * 6) goto L6; else goto L7;
                    }
                }
            }
            #define ur(i) f[(n + *p * i) / 32] &= m[(n + *p * i) % 32]
            ur(0); ur(1); ur(2); ur(3); ur(4); ur(5); ur(6); ur(7);
        }
        L7: ur(6);
        L6: ur(5);
        L5: ur(4);
        L4: ur(3);
        L3: ur(2);
        L2: ur(1);
        L1: ur(0);
        L0:
        p2 = sq(*++p);
        #undef ur
    } while (p2 < st + C * 16);
}
```

Comment: Try optimizing by replacing multiplication/division with left/right shifts wherever possible. For example `(a * 16)` can be written as `(a << 4)`.

Comment: @kiner_shah I'm fed up reading the assembly output. The compiler obviously does that.

Comment: Maybe ask in [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @kiner_shah Compilers do that kind of optimization anyway, even without optimizations enabled and even TCC (not exactly known for optimizing) does it: https://godbolt.org/z/eqhxGcP38

Comment: xiver77, Curious, why the `int d` and `(int)` casting and not `unsigned d = st + C * 16 - n;  if (d <= /* not cast */ *p * 14) {`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `d` can be negative.

Comment: Hmmm, `st + C * 16 - n` is never negative.   With `int d = st + C * 16 - n;`, are you relying on implementation define behavior to wrap `st + C * 16 - n` larger than `INT_MAX` to some negative `int`?

Comment: @xiver77 I still suspect the overflows code is experiencing and reliance on a negative `d` is not making for the correct functionality.  Good luck.

Comment: Tip: `d *d` in `for (unsigned d = 5, c = 4; d * d <= n; d += c ^= 6) { if (!(n % d)) goto next; }` is prone to overflow when `n` is a prime near `UINT_MAX`.  `d * d <= n;` --> `d <= n/d;` does not overflow for all `n` and is likely faster given the nearby `n%d`.
`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I just saw the values of variables printed when `d` is negative. It turns out that during the loop, when the multiple of `*p` reaches very close to `st + C * 16` which is the end, in the next iteration, `d` can be negative after `*p * 16` is added to `n`. The value of `d` cannot be negative due to overflow because `n` is always set to a value larger than `st`. The prime generation part is just a simple piece of code for test, and the maximum value of `n` is `65521`, which cannot overflow when squared.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica And yes, it seems correct that I'm relying on an implementation dependent behaviour on 2's complement machines for integer wrapping when converting from unsigned to signed.

Comment: "... and the maximum value of n is 65521, which cannot overflow when squared. " --> But it is not `n` being squared.  `d` is squared.  Although you are likely dealing with 32-bit, `d * d <= n` does overflow with 16-bit math as `d` becomes 257.  Be careful about [overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariane_5#Notable_launches) reasoning  in `fillPrimes()` and with `st + C * 16 - n`.  Good luck.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, your comments actually helped me double-check the parts I weren't thinking deeply.

Comment: @xiver77 Just another subtle coding point.  When code is not mathematically obviously sound, but needs deeper thought, the code "as is" may perform quickly (using subtle uncommented tricks), but becomes expensive to maintain - and maintenance costs exceeds development costs.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I wouldn't write a code for calculating prime numbers from the start if I was thinking about cost-effectiveness. This code essentially achieves nothing but my self enjoyment and possibly learning things during the process.

Comment: @pmg, the question needs work before it's suited to [codereview.se]. You should have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need a good description of the *purpose* of the code to give context, and question titles should simply say what the code *does* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.

Comment: Thanks @TobySpeight, I appreciate your input.

Comment: Is it Ok for you to use x86 SIMD instructions like AVX-2?

Comment: @JérômeRichard Yes, the other parts are already using AVX2 intrinsics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a simple benchmarking framework to test various approaches. It turns out the unrolling does not improve performance. The reason is probably that modern processors predict branches so a simple loop that runs many times can run at full speed, which is the case for small primes and the same simple loop that breaks immediately is also correctly predicted once primes become large enough.

Here is a simplified version with identical performance on my laptop:

```
static void sieve_bit_3(unsigned *f, unsigned st, unsigned *pp) {
    static const unsigned m[] = {
        ~(1u << 0),  ~(1u << 1),  ~(1u << 2),  ~(1u << 3),  ~(1u << 4),
        ~(1u << 5),  ~(1u << 6),  ~(1u << 7),  ~(1u << 8),  ~(1u << 9),
        ~(1u << 10), ~(1u << 11), ~(1u << 12), ~(1u << 13), ~(1u << 14),
        ~(1u << 15), ~(1u << 16), ~(1u << 17), ~(1u << 18), ~(1u << 19),
        ~(1u << 20), ~(1u << 21), ~(1u << 22), ~(1u << 23), ~(1u << 24),
        ~(1u << 25), ~(1u << 26), ~(1u << 27), ~(1u << 28), ~(1u << 29),
        ~(1u << 30), ~(1u << 31)
    };
    unsigned p = *pp;
    unsigned p2 = sq(p);
    do {
        unsigned n = (p2 > st + p * 2 ? p2 - st : p - st % p + (-(st % p & 1) & p)) / 2;
        for (; n < C * 8; n += p) {
            f[n / 32] &= m[n % 32];
        }
        p2 = sq(p = *++pp);
    } while (p2 < st + C * 16);
}
```

Here is a modified version with fewer tests, a little faster:

```
static void sieve_bit_6(unsigned *f, unsigned st, unsigned *pp) {
    static const unsigned m[] = {
        ~(1u << 0),  ~(1u << 1),  ~(1u << 2),  ~(1u << 3),  ~(1u << 4),
        ~(1u << 5),  ~(1u << 6),  ~(1u << 7),  ~(1u << 8),  ~(1u << 9),
        ~(1u << 10), ~(1u << 11), ~(1u << 12), ~(1u << 13), ~(1u << 14),
        ~(1u << 15), ~(1u << 16), ~(1u << 17), ~(1u << 18), ~(1u << 19),
        ~(1u << 20), ~(1u << 21), ~(1u << 22), ~(1u << 23), ~(1u << 24),
        ~(1u << 25), ~(1u << 26), ~(1u << 27), ~(1u << 28), ~(1u << 29),
        ~(1u << 30), ~(1u << 31)
    };
    unsigned p, p2;
    while (p = *pp++, (p2 = sq(p)) <= st + 2 * p) {
        unsigned mod = st % p;
        unsigned n = (p - mod + (-(mod & 1) & p)) / 2;
        for (; n < C * 8; n += p) {
            f[n / 32] &= m[n % 32];
        }
    }
    while (p2 < st + C * 16) {
        unsigned n = (p2 - st) / 2;
        for (; n < C * 8; n += p) {
            f[n / 32] &= m[n % 32];
        }
        p2 = sq(p = *pp++);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the same thing and only succeed to get a ~3% speed-up. Then, I tried AVX-2 gather instruction with all the index computed with AVX-2 too. Because AVX-2 does not have a scatter instruction, I used a manual serial scatter loop. This is not faster than the unrolled implementation (but about as fast). 33% of the time is spent in gather instructions, and 25% in the manual scatter. Computing instruction takes 10% of the time. 22% comes from the rest (final loop checking the last values, conditionals, etc.). Thus, the code is probably bound a lot by the latency of the L2 cache fetches.

Comment: Your second code is indeed a bit faster. Your point about unrolling related to branch prediction makes sense, but on my machine the unrolled version gained very slight (~2%?) advantage. There were some variances and I didn't test thoroughly, but at least the unrolled one was never slower, so I left it that way.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I am already using SIMD intrinsics wherever using it gains performance. I didn't use it here because the multiples of primes are already scattered due to the large base prime size, and as you mentioned, there is no "scatter" instruction in AVX2.

Comment: I'm about to work on *jumping* the multiples. Currently only the even numbers are jumped by adding `p * 2`. Multiples of 3 can also be avoided by alternately adding `p * 2` and `p * 4`. Multiples of more primes can be avoided with a more complicated *wheel*. I'll have to test what works best.

Comment: Does the simplified version really have identical performance to the unrolled one on your machine? In terms of `rdtscp` cycles, the simple one averages to 1.75 billion while the unrolled one is to 1.4 billion on mine.

Comment: @xiver77: The costly operation is the modulo for large primes. You might gain some performance by keeping track of moduli across iterations to avoid the costly division instruction, or convert these divisions to multiplications by pre-computing the appropriate multiplier for each prime.

Answer (score 0):

You might be sieving, but what about counting? And a upper limit, so one can compare? And OMP like `primesieve`?

You are stuck because you are not even counting or comparing, only with yourself.

I made a segmented sieve just with a 30Kb `char` array. At 2 billion, it takes quite exactly 3 times as long as `primesieve`, and works with OMP. So all your bit mapping and unrolling is  not measurable.

```
$ time primesieve 2000000000
Sieve size = 128 KiB
Threads = 8
100%
Seconds: 0.089
Primes: 98222287

real    0m0.094s
user    0m0.655s
sys     0m0.013s
```

A non-sieve (not even multi-threading at this number):

```
$ time primecount 2000000000
98222287

real    0m0.087s
user    0m0.018s
sys     0m0.013s
```

My simple char sieve:

```
$ time ./a.out 2000000000
PI (prime count) of 
2000000000 (2e+09): 
98222287

real    0m0.311s
user    0m2.456s
sys     0m0.004s
```

"sweating" on 8 threads. Without the limit, and the result, what does `0.311s` mean?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I did mention `primesieve` in the OP. That program is about 2.8x faster than the current version of mine.